# Black screen when creating movie

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I've rendered about 300 frames for a short clip. The frames look fine, but when I compile into a movie all I get is a black screen. I haven't been able to find anything to solve this problem. The individual frames are well lit, capture what I want them to, look great. Just creating the AVI or MPEG results in a clip that has nothing but black.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what happens if you scrub to somewhere in the middle and render a single frame? You have several cameras set up, it is possible that the Scene camera is not the one you think. Properties->Scene->Camera

Comment: Well now I can't seem to render anything. I don't know what I broke, but I just get the second screen above

Comment: it says there are no layers in your render result, can you show a crop of your layers tab ?

Comment: Is the third picture above what you're looking for?

Comment: also your Start / End clip in the viewport View tab are set to 0.01 -> 100000000000376832.00 that makes no sense

Comment: if the file isn't too big consider uploading to : http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  and give it a password so you can choose to delete it after it's resolved.

Comment: it looks like you've added all the keyframes to `Camera` and not the other cameras..not the camera you have active for the scene

Answer (score 5):

You have an unused video strip in the VSE and in the Post processing options you have sequence enabled. That makes the Video Sequence Editor take precedence and it will not render your scene, but whatever is happening on the VSE. Disable the sequence box and you'll be able to render your scene.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is why I recommend that VSE and 3D scenes should be kept separate.  http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/render-to-pngs.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been pulling my hair out for the last day trying to figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your render layers are good.

What is the start/end clip on your camera object?

If you have any strips in the VSE they can confuse things (always use a separate Scene for 3D versus VSE).

Your screenshots appear to clip off the right side of the outliner where the camera icon indicates whether the object is rendered or not.  Check that.

Throw in a cube 2 units in front of the camera and make sure that appears.

It is preferred practice to render your animation to a sequence of stills and encode them into an animation in a separate step (either using blender's VSE or ffmpeg).  It seems you're going straight from 3d model to AVI which would make it hard to interrupt and resume your render.  While that's no big deal on short simple animations, it really becomes important when you have a 1600 frame animation where each frame takes 3.5 minutes to render on your laptop.

If all else fails you can upload your .blend file to [pasteall.org](http://pasteall.org/) and ask IRC #blender for help.  Make sure the answer gets posted here for you to accept.

Comment: 1 Clip is 1-10000

Comment: 1 Clip is 1-10000

I can get a cube to appear in camera view, but nothing renders anymore

I did render as a sequence of stills. I used VSE to get the black screen video for 300 frames. 

I just loaded to pasteall - http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36171. Unfortunately I'm being blocked at work from installing IRC. I'll keep trying but if anyone wants to download my blender file and tell me why I can't render or compile previous renderings into a video I would be most appreciative!