# Render view does not match final render (Cycles Render)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have a shot put together with a model that is textured to my standards and lit to match my scene and I like the way it looks in the render view.

My issue is that this does not match what shows up in the render.

(The positioning is a little different, but you get the idea).

Anyhow, I've been tinkering around in the settings and can't get it to look right. I'm pretty new to this program and was wondering if I may just have some of my settings messed up or if it's an issue with my laptop rendering. Any thoughts?

Thanks, Joel

Here's my node setup for the material.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post your .blend file using [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: One of the possible causes is the fact that you have some hidden lamps (so they don't cast light) but enabled when rendering. Could you post the dinosaur's skin node setup too?

Comment: Check for hidden lamps using [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33787/why-is-part-of-my-model-not-being-rendered/33790#33790).

Comment: I updated my post with my node setup and also the file.

Comment: You have a strip in the VSE that 's taking over precedence on whatever you render. Uncheck the Sequencer button button on the PostPorcessing tab for the scene. see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31243/black-screen-when-creating-movie/31264#31264