# My Blender File Isn't Rendering

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

My blender file is rendering but the rendered images are all black.
Here is the Blender file:

[image]

[image: It Says its rendering, but it just creates black files.]

Comment: Could you explain in more details what problems are there with your file other than posting a link to download? (by the way use [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) when sharing files on this site please) What are you creating, what problems did you face, what did you do to troubleshoot etc. For now your question is a bit like "do it for me" which is off topic on this site.

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Came back to a blender file, now not rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering) and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31243/black-screen-when-creating-movie and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14377/render-turns-black-when-finished and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18884/cycles-final-render-pitch-black/18895#18895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ray was correct in the above comments.

The Compositor and Sequence settings are enabled by default, so if there is any data in the compositor or the sequencer blender will render from that instead of the scene.

[image]

Or go to your sequencer and delete that info.

[image]