# Tracked footage renders but not the 3D object

Tags: rendering, tracking

My 3d object doesn't render. Only the tracked footage appears when I try to render the scene. What could be the problem ?

[image: Layout]
[image: Render]

Here's the .blend file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/194iS-WFTLlGNtrLZ-7vMW65P0wfpIX3R/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got it ! However, I couldn't find a solution to my problem on the forum or elsewhere. So I thought uploading the actual file was the only way to know where I messed up. If someone comes up with a solution to my problem, I'll make sure to post the solution like you suggested. Thanks :)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank See #4 also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51179/blank-image-when-i-render and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31243/black-screen-when-creating-movie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, in the *Output Properties* under *Post Processing* > *Pipeline* the *Sequencer* is enabled. This is by default and usually no problem when you create a 3D scene and want to render it, **as long as there is nothing in the *Sequencer*.**

[image: sequencer in pipeline]

But you have a strip with a movie clip there, so the *Sequencer* determines what the output shows - and there is no strip for the scene. The problem now is, you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Add* > *Scene*, but the only option available there is "New Scene", you cannot choose the active scene in which you are in.

[image: add new scene strip]

To do this, you have to create a new scene with the *New* button next to the scene name. I would not copy the original scene but start with a completely new scene.

[image: create new scene]

If you now go to *Video Editing* and try to add a scene strip, there appears the name of the other scene ("Scene") to choose it as input. This way you can have many different scenes where you create 3D contents and additionally have one scene only for the video editing. In your case you have to add the movie clip there as well of course.

[image: add existing scene strip]

If you just want to render your object to see how it looks and do not care for the movie clip, you can disable the *Sequencer* in the post processing pipeline while you render.

If you do not want to use the *Sequencer* from the *Video Editing* at all, you can go there, delete the strip containing the movie clip and since it's the only one, your scene will now be rendered normally. To get the movie clip in the background you can add it in the *Compositor* and use an *Alpha Overlay* node to composite the 3D scene above it.

Comment: Hey @Gordon Brinkmann could you copy paste this answer over to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank/ ? Feel free to ping me there for a free upvote

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I did post it there now as well, but I saw the reason I give in my answer is already there, only that their solution to that is a bit simpler... just disabling the sequencer.

Comment: Yes, yours is a little more thorough, that is why i think it is a good addition. Thanks for posting!

Comment: It worked ! Thank you so much :)