# Is it possible to place a camera view from the 3d viewport in the video sequencer?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I am a beginner at blender so please bear with  me.
I am looking to bring together a video in blender made of multiple camera cuts as well as other graphics such as text and audio from outside blender. I thought i would be able to use the video editing capability built in blender to cut between multiple 3d viewport cameras.

Is it possible to bring 3d viewport cameras into the video sequencer?
I somewhat understand the idea of using the different scenes and how that can be used. I think i only need one scene though. I cannot find a way to put a camera view from the current scene into the video sequencer.

I am running blender 4.0.1
Thank you for you time and assistance!!

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure to understand, the only things you can put in the Video Sequencer are images, sounds and video, if you want to put something from your 3D view you need to render the 3D view animation first, but you should better use another file to manage the Video Sequencer, it's a bit confusing to mix 3D scene and video editing in the same file imho

Comment: You might only need one scene for your project, but in the _Video Sequence Editor_ you can only add scene strips of scenes that are not the one you are editing the video in. I explain it a little bit in my answer to this question: [Tracked footage renders but not the 3D object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/297764/tracked-footage-renders-but-not-the-3d-object/297767#297767)